# Why I'm getting this error: "Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm trying to make a simple distributed database with ***Oracle Database 11g***. I've created 2 virtual machines, both windows 7 and I've set up static ip for everyone and then I've modified the ***listener.ora***. For exmaple the ***listener.ora*** for first VM looks like this:
[image]

I've check from my PC with ping to see if I get a reply and it works.
Then I've modified the ***tnsnames.ora*** from my PC as shown:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

SERVER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.75.131)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = XE)
    )
  )

SERVER2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.75.130)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = XE)
    )
  )
```

When I try to create a connection with hostname: *192.168.75.131*(first VM) I'm getting the follow error:  *Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied*.
The username and password are correct.
[image]

Comment: You say the username and password are correct, but oracle says differently.  Oracle is too dumb to lie about this. The fact that you are using a SQL Dev connection type of "basic" means that your tnsnames.ora doesn't even come into play.  And since this error comes from the database itself, it means you've already gotten past the listener, so your listener config does not come into play - at least not directly.  Have you considered case-sensitivity for your password? Either you are not hitting the db you think, or you are simply not entering a valid username/password combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect utilizing sqlplus on Server1 - the devops way - repeatable

```
C:\>set LOCAL=192.168.75.131/XE
C:\>sqlplus system/system_password
SQL>connect admin/admin_password
```

You can also try:

```
C:\>set LOCAL=localhost/XE
C:\>sqlplus system/system_password
SQL>connect admin/admin_password
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is your database set to use case-sensitive passwords?
That **could** be the issue.